# Need help creating search view and how to apply in the HTML page from DB that I created - Django

Tags: html, django

I am building a website with DJANGO where people put words and association how to remember the word.
I built the part of inserting the word.

I am now stuck in the part of implementing the word search and extracting the information from the DB.

```
def Search_word(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    search = request.POST["search"]
    word = Words.objects.filter(English_word__contains = search)
    return render(request,"search_page.html",{word:word , search:search})
else:
    return render(request,"search_page.html",{})

    {% if search %}
<h1> You searched for {{search}}</h1>

{% for Words in search %}
    {{Words.English_word}}
    {{ Words.Hebrew_word }}
    {{ Words.How_To_Remember}}
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
  <h1> Hey! You Forgot To Search </h1>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to search only in one field, Django supports search which is much better and more accurate than contains

```
words = Words.objects.filter(English_word__search = search_term)
```

but if you like to have some sort of search engine-like functionality you can use **PostgreSQL** with **Django's full text** search feature

in **model.py** add these commands

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
```

in your **model manger**:

```
def full_search(self, search_term):
      return self.annotate( 
            search=SearchVector('English_word') + 
            SearchVector('blog__tagline')).filter(search=seach_term)
```

this method will remove <in/at/is/the/...> other English words and only search with word-to-vector algorithms

if you have to work with ranking the search results:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank,SearchVector

vector = SearchVector('english_word')
query = SearchQuery(search_term)
Word.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).order_by('-rank')
```

this will annotate the results based on their likelihood to search term.

by the way It's best practice to use Model Mangers and avoid doing ORM stuff in views.

Django Docs on search:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Comment: thanks ! after checking again I'm thinking I wrote the function well and now I need some help how to apply it on the html page